# Autocomplete tag angular not working in iphone

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ng2-tag-input, ngx-chips

I have used ngx-chips autocomplete feature. Its works in desktop and in android devices but its shows no suggestion in Iphone.

Here is my code :

```
<tag-input name="item" [(ngModel)]="item" [secondaryPlaceholder]="'Enter business name'" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true" [placeholder]="'Business name'">
                                <tag-input-dropdown [showDropdownIfEmpty]="true" [focusFirstElement]="true" [displayBy]="'value'" [identifyBy]="'id'" [autocompleteItems]="autocompleteItemsAsObjects">
                                  <ng-template let-item="item" let-index="index">
                                    {{ item.value }}
                                  </ng-template>
                                </tag-input-dropdown>
                        </tag-input>
```

And this is my autocompleteItemsAsObjects object:

```
  autocompleteItemsAsObjects = [
{value: 'Comuna Cantina - Pacific Fair', id: 0},
{value: 'Comuna Cantina - Albert Lane', id: 1},
{value: 'Corbett & Claude - Rhodes', id: 2},    
{value: 'Corbett & Claude - Garden City', id: 3},    
{value: 'Corbett & Claude - Indooroopilly', id: 4},        ];
```

The reference I have used is https://pixinvent.com/apex-angular-4-bootstrap-admin-template/demo-1/components/tags
The template works in Iphone but my code doesn't.

Comment: are you able to solve it? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57054429/9315263

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable all JavaScript and pop/ups in order to get that functionality.
In chrome you can go to settings->site settings->find JavaScript's and enable it

Comment: Thats not helping

Comment: can you provide a URL of that deployed app?